# redis attempting to connect to local host in Heroku - WHY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I have been using sidekiq/redis for quite some time with no issues to date.

For some reason, today I am getting this error:

`Redis::CannotConnectError - Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED):`

So, Redis is attempting to connect to my localhost connection instead of my redis_to_go url in heroku.

My redis.rb file looks like so:

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/")
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

And when I type `heroku config` I am given this:

```
REDISTOGO_URL: redis://redistogo:b9f872ce1dd16cd989@albacore.redistogo.com:10280/
```

which maps exactly to my url that I am seeing in my Redis To Go addon in Heroku.

Nothing changed with Redis that I know of between yesterday when it worked and today when it doesn't, but I did spin up a Mongo DB using Mongo HQ. Perhaps there is a conflict somewhere?

Any help is appreciated.

## EDIT

I have no mongo init file, and the only mongo specific file I created was my `config/mongoid.yml` file. It looks like this:

```
development:
   sessions:
     default:
       database: mongoid_dev
       hosts:
        - localhost:27017
   options: #strictly 2 spaces before
     raise_not_found_error: false #strictly 4 spaces before not 6
 
 production:
   sessions:
     default:
       uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
   options: #strictly 2 spaces before
     raise_not_found_error: false #strictly 4 spaces before not 6
```

I installed Mongo from Master and am running rails 4.1.0.

## EDIT2

Full trace error is below:

```
2014-04-15T20:33:05.068810+00:00 app[web.1]: Redis::CannotConnectError - Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED):
2014-04-15T20:33:05.068810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:290:in `rescue in establish_connection'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.068810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:285:in `establish_connection'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.068810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:79:in `block in connect'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.068810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:257:in `with_reconnect'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.068810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:78:in `connect'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.068810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:304:in `ensure_connected'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.068810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:191:in `block in process'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.068810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:270:in `logging'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.068810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:190:in `process'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069016+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:96:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069016+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:186:in `block in info'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069016+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:37:in `block in synchronize'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069016+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069016+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:37:in `synchronize'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069016+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:185:in `info'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069016+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/web.rb:218:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Web>'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069016+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/connection_pool-2.0.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:58:in `with'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069016+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq.rb:69:in `redis'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069016+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/web.rb:218:in `block in <class:Web>'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069244+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1603:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069244+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1603:in `block in compile!'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069244+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:966:in `[]'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069244+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:966:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069244+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:985:in `route_eval'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069244+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sinatra.rb:133:in `route_eval_with_newrelic'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069244+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:966:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069244+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1006:in `block in process_route'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069244+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1004:in `catch'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069244+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1004:in `process_route'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069903+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sinatra.rb:116:in `process_route_with_newrelic'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069903+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:964:in `block in route!'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069903+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:963:in `each'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069903+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:963:in `route!'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069903+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1076:in `block in dispatch!'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069903+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `block in invoke'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069903+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `catch'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069903+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `invoke'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069903+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in `dispatch!'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.069903+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sinatra.rb:151:in `dispatch_and_notice_errors_with_newrelic'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070192+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sinatra.rb:146:in `block in dispatch_with_newrelic'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070192+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:335:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070192+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sinatra.rb:143:in `dispatch_with_newrelic'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070192+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:898:in `block in call!'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070192+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `block in invoke'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070192+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `catch'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070192+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `invoke'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070192+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:898:in `call!'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070192+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:886:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070192+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:55:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070654+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:27:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070654+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:32:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070654+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070654+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070654+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:18:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070654+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070654+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070654+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070654+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/nulllogger.rb:9:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070654+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:180:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2014:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1478:in `block in call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1788:in `synchronize'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1478:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.070976+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:55:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:32:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:27:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071665+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071665+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071665+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071665+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071665+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071665+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071665+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071665+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071665+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.071665+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072148+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072148+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072148+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072148+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072148+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072148+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072148+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072148+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072148+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072148+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072577+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072577+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072577+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072577+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072577+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072577+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:572:in `process_client'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072577+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:666:in `worker_loop'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072577+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:22:in `call'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072577+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.3.204/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.072577+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:521:in `spawn_missing_workers'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.073631+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.073631+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.073631+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2014-04-15T20:33:05.073631+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: can you try simplifying your initializer with just `Redis.new(url: (ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'))` ; this is all I have in my file.

Comment: @blotto No dice. I even took out the `or localhost` piece of that and it still doesn't work. It has to be grabbing that local host URL from somewhere else it seems.

Comment: my guess is code elsehwere in your project is not grabbing the inits Redis object.  go to heroku console and do a few quick tests.. 1) `p ENV['REDISTOGO_URL']` 2) `Redis.new(url: (ENV['REDISTOGO_URL']))`  ; if this indeed points to albacore and not localhost, the your project code simply does not access your initialized object. i'll recommend some configs in a proposed answer next

Comment: They do indeed both point to albacore - Time to backtrace and find out what's wrong I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the ENV variable:

Per sidekiq's documentation:

> RedisToGo can be used with the default REDISTOGO_URL env var in
>   Sidekiq 2.x and earlier (REDISTOGO_URL is supported for legacy
>   reasons, the REDIS_PROVIDER and REDIS_URL vars are recommended).

You must use the `REDIS_PROVIDER` or `REDIS_URL` ENV varibles instead of the `REDISTOGO_URL` for sidekiq 3 and up. You do not need a sidekiq initializer, and this code will do the trick:

Run the following from your terminal

`heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=redis://...........`

Comment: REDIS_PROVIDER is not meant to hold the actual URL - it's meant to hold the name of the ENV var which contains the URL.  So it should be literally `REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL`.

Answer (score 47):

I had the same problem. Sidekiq 3+ does NOT automatically recongnize REDISTOGO_URL environment variable, instead REDIS_PROVIDER is used . I did a config reference by:

```
heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL
```

then problem solved

I give detail explanation in my [blog post](http://blog.minus1.se/2014/05/caution-sidekiq3-changed-recognized.html)

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: @DipakPanchal, I am glad it helps!

Answer (score 0):

set up your redis.rb file as such :

```
 module MyApp
   class << self
     def redis
       @redis ||= Redis.new(url: (ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'))
     end
   end
 end
```

in your sidekiq.rb do  :

```
 Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|

   Rails.logger = Sidekiq::Logging.logger

   config.redis = { :url => MyApp.redis[:url], :namespace => 'sidekiq', :size => 5 }
 end

 Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
   config.redis = { :url => MyApp.redis[:url], :namespace => 'sidekiq', :size => 1 }
 end
```

this will ensure Sidekiq is picking up the Redis connection from your redis.rb init file.

Comment: bahh copied that exactly with no luck. I rolled my app back to before I setup MongoHQ and it works fine. There has to be something I'm doing in the setup of Mongo to mess things up.

Comment: yea..I wonder if Mongo is overriding some of your Redis configs.  maybe post your inits for Mongo too.